# SQLite database Where clause not working for text datatype Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, where-clause

I want to write a Where clause for Sqlite db & my query is as follows,

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(table_name,new String[]{COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3}, COLUMN_1='1', null, null, null, null);

//COLUMN_1='1' is my WHERE Clause & its datatype is text
```

I am not able to execute this query & its giving Nullpointer exception immediately after this statement.
I dont know the reason I think there is some problem with text datatype.

I have spent almost half a day searching for the solution but disappointed.

PS: I've also tried using ,

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(table_name,new String[]{COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3}, COLUMN_1=?, new String[] {'1'}, null, null, null);
```

**LogCat:**

[image: Below is my LogCat]

But Same problem.

Comment: didn't you forgot quotes around your String ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: also, as always, post stacktrace.

Comment: When you get an NPE *after* this statement, why don't you show the code after this statement?

Comment: @ njzk2: no, I have used single quotes(').

Comment: Reason of downwoting? Mr. Downvoter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you initialize the database? Do you have anything like this:

```
database = new DBAdapter(this);
```

Also you need to open the database before the query.

```
database.open();
```

Comment: Yes , I have open the database.

Comment: Rest all is working well with the db ,e.g. Creating,Inserting ,etc. But there is some problem with the fetch query.

Comment: Cursor cursor = database.query(table_name,new String[]{COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3}, COLUMN_1='1', null, null, null, null);

Comment: oh ok, cuz you said its immediately after this statement. Only thing i can think of is to check your variables not to be null. Either the database, the table or the columns.

Check a sample form my code also. I have a boolean at start and i have 5 nulls at the end. Not sure if this will help but give it a try.
  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, MY_LOCATIONS_TABLE, new String[] { MY_LOCATION_NAME, MY_LOCATION_NUMBER, MY_LOCATION_CODE }, MY_LOCATION_NAME + "='" + locationName + "'",
    null, null, null, null, null);

Comment: waaait. Try to add double quotes for the = sign and for the single quotes.  "= '1' "

Comment: public Cursor getLocationName(String alarmNumber) throws SQLException {


  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, MY_LOCATIONS_TABLE, new String[] { MY_LOCATION_NAME }, MY_LOCATION_NUMBER + "='" + alarmNumber + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, the database was not opened & hence giving NPE. Thank you guys for your patience.

Comment: Because you provided me the step that I was missing while dealing with the sqlite db.

Comment: yes i gave you the answer u needed. Unaccepting my answer takes points off from me. Since i answered your question then you mark me as a correct answer.

Comment: And thats y you will see many people say if that if i helped you or was the correct answer then mark it as correct answer. You dont unnaccept the correct answer and make a new one on your own and say that this thing helped me. You mark the one who helped you